# Running multiple JUnit Tests with ANT for Regression and Granularity

Tags: unit-testing, ant, build, junit, regression

I'm trying to set up an ANT build script which compile code, compile tests, run unittests and then build. These are all done through separate targets with dependencies i.e.

```
<target name="compile">
  <javac>...
</target>
<target name="compile-tests" depends="compile">
  <javac>...
</target>
<target name="unittest" depends="compile-tests">
  <junit...
   <test ...
  <fail if="tests.failed" ..
</target>
<target name="build" depends="compile, unittest">
</target>
```

Each 'test' inside the 'junit' task focuses on one part of the application, (typically package by package) and points to a Junit TestSuite. This set up allows for all tests to be run when a build is called but this isn't ideal for day-to-day development.

I would like to be able to do 2 things:

1. Run all the tests in a build (like the setup shown above)
2. Run tests individually from ant

My solution for (2) was to use multiple antcall tasks which isn't really best practice. During these calls different properties were set to run all the tests as they each required a different property:

```
<!-- test package p2 with ant unittest -Dtest.p2=true -->
<target name="unittest" depends="compile-tests">
  <junit...
   <test if="test.p1" ...
   <test if="test.p2"
  <fail if="tests.failed" ..
</target>

<target name="unittestall">
  <property name="test.p1" value="true"/>
   ...
</target>

<target name="build" depends="compile, unittest">
  <antcall target="unittestall" />
  <antcall target="clean" />
  <antcall target="compile" />
</target>
```

This gave the granularity I required but meant alot of work was duplicated and ant's dependency features weren't being used to their full.

So my question is:
How can I best set up ANT and Junit so that all tests can be run as part of a build AND so that individual tests can be run?

Thankyou :)

from Joshua England

p.s. ANT 1.8 and Junit 4.10 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<target name="unittest-p1"></target>
<target name="unittest-p2"></target>
<target name="unittest-p3"></target>

<target name="unittest" depends="unittest-p1, unittest-p2, unittest-p3/>
```

You could then run all the tests by passing the unittest target:

```
ant unittest
```

(or any target which depends on unittest)

And you could run any individual test of set of tests by invoking the appropriate target, e.g.

```
ant unittest-p1
```

If you would end up with a lot of duplication in multiple junit targets, you could tidy that up by putting all the common stuff into a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html).

Comment: ant unittest-p1

will run only the first set without the use of properties.

Comment: that seems a nicer solution in terms of avoiding properties but it does mean there's alot more junit tasks in the build script and alot of repeated stuff BUT it does give alot of flexibility. I'll give this way a go and see how I get on.